# Querying XML in Solr

Tags: xml, solr, lucene

I have some XML stored in Solr that looks like this:

```
<MainInfo>
  <Info>
    <Info name="Bob" city="Columbus" />
    <Info name="Joe" city="Cincinnati" />
  </Info>
</MainInfo>
```

What I’d like to do is get a hit for this document if there’s an element in the XML where (@name=”Bob” AND @city=”Cincinnati”). If I write something like this, I’ll get a hit – although I’m not actually matching what I’m looking for:

q=MainData.Info.Info@name:Bob AND MainData.Info.Info@city:Cincinnati

I want to my criteria only to match attributes within the same element, for example:

```
<MainData>
  <Info>
    <Info name="Bob" city="Columbus" />
    <Info name="Joe" city="Cincinnati" />
    <Info name="Bob" city="Cincinnati" /> (only match this) 
  </Info>
</MainData>
```

Is it possible to write a query to achieve this without changing my XML?

Comment: How exactly have you stored this XML document in Solr? Can you post your actual Solr docs?

Comment: Solr does not support this kind of queries. One approach that we implemented is to index each tag as a separate document with ancestor information and the attributes

Answer (score 0):

Solr doesn't support storing an xml and querying on it, at least the way you are asking. It supports xml structure wile indexing and querying, but it has a specific structure. Please refer https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages.

But the result you are looking for, that can be achieved by defining Solr supported document structure.

```
<MainData>
  <Info>
    <Info name="Bob" city="Columbus" />
    <Info name="Joe" city="Cincinnati" />
    <Info name="Bob" city="Cincinnati" /> (only match this) 
  </Info>
</MainData>
```

For above example, please refer the above URL and create 3 different solr documents. Then if you query `name:Bob AND city:Cincinnati`, it will return you the matched document.